# VPN breaks internet with new router

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

I had a working internet and VPN connection  (openconnect) on a Ubuntu 15.04  I then got a new router that changed my LAN ips.  I went from a 10.x.x.x  to a 192.168.x.x, and now when I vpn,  I loose all internet,  while anything on the VPN is fine.

I have disabled all firewalls on my laptop and on the router. Here is my netstat, while I am vpn'd in,  and as you can see,  there is 2 entries for 192.168.0.0 - I am assuming this is the problem.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp62s0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 vpn0
10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U         0 0          0 vpn0
54.175.25.57    192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 wlp62s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 wlp62s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U         0 0          0 vpn0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlp62s0
```

I also have access to a wi-fi signal from comcast that uses a 10.x.x.x and when I am on that,  everything works fine.  here is the netstat while I am vpn'd in:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.224.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp62s0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 vpn0
10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U         0 0          0 vpn0
10.224.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.224.0.0     U         0 0          0 wlp62s0
54.175.25.57    10.224.0.1      255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 wlp62s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 wlp62s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U         0 0          0 vpn0
```

No dual entries here.

So what is happening, why, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VPN is advertising that IP addresses 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.0.127 can be reached through it (second last line of first route list) - This IP range overlaps with your ethernet range of 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.0.254 (last line).

Because the VPN route is more specific it is preferred, and causing you problems.   There are a few ways you can fix this problem, but in essence, you need to renumber your LAN so that it does not conflict with OpenVPN, and, ideally that it does not overlap.

You can potentially do this by changing your OpenVPN config that it does not advertise the 192.168.0.0/25 range [ but if you have other hosts in that range on the other side of the VPN you will no longer be able to reach them ], or you can renumber your network out that range - for example, change your LAN network to 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0

Comment: The VPN is a 10.x.x.x network,  is the fact that it is advertising that 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.0.127  can be reached by it a configuration error on the VPN side?

Comment: I was able to configure the router to 192.168.1.0 and it all worked fine.

Comment: If there are no hosts in 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.0.127 on the remote side of the VPN, yes, its an error in the VPN config.  Most likely on the server side, but it could be client side config as well.